# Convergence of the integral of positive part sequence of measurable function

Tags: integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $( X, \Sigma , \mu)$ be a measure Space
and $(f_n)$ be a sequence of Borel measurable
functions. Suppose that $f _ { n } \rightarrow f$ Point wise and $\lim _ { n \rightarrow \infty } \int f _ { n } d \mu = \int f d \mu < \infty$,
then Show that if $ f _ { n }^ + \rightarrow f^+$ pointwise,
then $\int f _ { n } ^ { + } d { \mu } \longrightarrow \int f ^ { + } d \mu$

My attempt:

Since $f _ { n }$ is an $L^+$ function, we have
$f _ { n } ^ { + } = \max\left( f _ { n } , 0 \right)$ is an $L^+$ function,
Thus by Fatou's Lemma, we have
$$\int \liminf f _ { n } ^+\leqslant \liminf \int f _ { n }^+$$
ie $\int f ^ { + } \leq \liminf _ { n \rightarrow \infty } \int f _ { n } ^ { + }$, Now what i have to do?

Comment: By $L^+$, do you mean the set of measurable functions $X \to [0, \infty]$? If so, then $f_n = f_n^+$, by definition.

Comment: Ya.....you are correct, but I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong. Consider $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ and $$f_n(x) := n 1_{(0,1/n)}(x) - n 1_{(1-1/n,1)}(x).$$ Then $f_n \to f:=0$ pointwise, $f_n^+ \to f^+$ pointwise and $\int f_n \, d\lambda=0=\int f \, d\lambda$. On the other hand,

$$\int f_n^+ \, d\lambda=1$$
does not converge to $\int f^+ \, d\lambda=0$.